# Constantly getting 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, algorithmic-trading

I am working on an algorithmic trading strategy. In df1 I have rows corresponding to times 9.15 am and 9.20 am for each day in a month In df2 I have rows corresponding to time 9.26 for each day in a month In df3 I have rows corresponding to each minute starting from 9.15 am for each day in a month.

I have to compare the closing price at 9.20 am and 9.25 am for each day in a month and subsequently make decisions.

So I started with x as 1 and df1 and df2 and then iterated till the end of df1. Did x =1 as I am doing x-1 so for the first iteration it might give me -1 as the index, so to avoid that did x=1 and similarly started with y=0 for df3 and now when comparing it is giving the strings error

Below is the code of the iteration:

```
profit=0
x=1
y=1
for x in range(len(df)):
#     green candle. i.e closing price of 9.25 is greater than closing price of 9.20, i.e prices have increased
#     then  we keep target as price at 9.26-50 and sl as price at 9.26 + 50
    if df['close'].iloc[x] > df['close'].iloc[x-1]:
        short=df['close'].iloc[x]
        sl = df2['open'].iloc[x]+50
        tgt =df2['open'].iloc[x]-50 
        for y in range (len(df3)):
            if(sl==df3['open'].iloc[y]): 
                profit+=(df3['open'].iloc[y]-short)
            elif(tgt==df3['open'].iloc[y]):
                profit+=(df3['open'].iloc[y]-short)      
        x+=1



    elif df['close'].iloc[x] < df['close'].iloc[x-1]:
        long=df['close'].iloc[x]
        sl = df2['open'].iloc[x]-50
        tgt =df2['open'].iloc[x]+50 
        for y in range(len(df3)):
            if(sl==df3['open'].iloc[y]):
                profit+=(df3['open'].iloc[y]-short)
            elif(tgt==df3['open'].iloc[y]):
                profit+=(df3['open'].iloc[y]-short)      
        x+=1
        
profit
```

Am getting the error single positional indexer is out-of-bounds. I tried changing the starting limit of x and y but still, the error is there.

Below I have also attached the pic of the df enter image description here Any help is highly appreciated!!

[image]

I am getting the below error

[image]

I tried searching on the net, but couldn't find a suitable solution to resolve it.

Comment: Snippets in the screenshots don't match your codes pasted in the body of the question.

Comment: Check your `df` object types. Atleast one of them will not be a dataframe.

Comment: Firstly, I suggest you to `print(df2["open"])`, `type(df2["open"])` to see how it looks like. Secondly, I suggest you provide some parts of your data so people can use them as test cases to find whether our solution is correct.